# unicode error python quando importo campos com texto com acentuacao

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

Estou com um erro quando executo o comando abaixo, gera o arquivo de texto corretamente quando importo textos do banco de dados sem acentuação, porém quando há alguma acentuação aparece o erro:

> File "C:/Users/ti/Desktop/relatorio.py", line 17, in doQuery rows = cur.fetchall() UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 272: ordinal not in range(128)

```
hostname = '192.168.0.50'
username = 'aasd'
password = 'asdasd'
database = 'db1'


def doQuery( conn ):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    comando_sql = """SELECT os.numos, 
             ccusto.nomecc,prest.nomeprest,equip.especifica
             from osmanut as os 
             left join cadcc as ccusto on os.codccserv = ccusto.codcc 
             left join cadprest as prest on os.prestsolic = prest.codprest 
             left join cadeqman as equip on os.codequipa = equip.codequipa 
             where codtecos = '007' and CAST(os.dataconclu AS DATE) = '2017-07-05' order by os.numos"""
    cur.execute (comando_sql)
    arq = open("relatorio_diario.txt", "w")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        numos = row[0]
        setor = row[1]
        solicitante = row[2]
        equip_nome = row[3]
        solicitante = solicitante if solicitante is not None else "Nao Informado"
        equip_nome = equip_nome if equip_nome is not None else "Nao Informado"
        arq.write('_OS: {} - Setor: {} - Solicitante: {}\n - Equipamento: {}\n Resolucao: '.format(numos, setor, solicitante, equip_nome))
        arq.write("\n")
        arq.write("------------------------------------------------------")
        arq.write("\n")
        arq.close()

import psycopg2
myConnection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
doQuery( myConnection )
myConnection.close()
```

Comment: Foi erro ao colar aqui.

Comment: Eu não tenho experiência com o psycopg2, mas desconfio que algum comando adicional seja necessário caso queira lidar com dados unicode. Qual a codificação do seu banco de dados? Talvez seja necessário usar `myConnection.set_client_encoding("...")` antes de chamar `doQuery`, passando o mesmo encoding do seu BD como argumento. P.S. Talvez eu esteja enganado, o tratamento de unicode no python 2 e no python 3 é diferente. Sugiro dar uma olhada [nessa seção da documentação](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#unicode-handling), não sei te dizer exatamente o que fazer, mas talvez dê uma ideia.

Comment: Saberia me informar qual outro posso utilizar sem ser o psycopg2? Meu banco de dados eh em postgresql

Comment: Se vai se conectar com o Postgres, o psycopg2 é mesmo a melhor solução, não conheço outra... É só o caso de descobrir como usá-la corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ter certeza que vc está usando a codificação correta, tente o comando:

print (myConnection.encoding)

A saida deveria ser:

```
UTF8
```

Se não for tente configurar com o comando:

```
myConnection.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
```

Ou:

```
myConnection.set_client_encoding('UNICODE')
```

Se nada disso resolver e voce tiver acesso ao arquivo de configuração do Postgres, `postgresql.conf` confira as linhas referentes às configurações `lc_`, um bloco parecido com esse:

```
# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'         # locale for system error message
# strings
lc_monetary = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'         # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'          # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'             # locale for time formatting
```

Comment: Po amigao, deu crto o comando.
O print mostrava SQLASCII como encoding
executei o comando 
myConnection.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
e funcionou corretamente

Brigadao e boa sexta

Comment: Ok, considere dar o aceite (clicando no sinal proximo ao numero de votos) na questao, Obrigado.